# What are good references for learning Biophysics at the graduate level for a biochemist/experimental molecular biologist?

Tags: resource-recommendations, biophysics

I recently started graduate school in the fields of molecular biology and genetics. Over the past few months I have been gaining a strong interest in mechanotransduction and tissue engineering. While reading the literature, I realized that I am unable to understand the technical aspects of characterizing the mechanical environment of cells and tissue. I would really like to learn more about this area.

I have a strong biology and biochemistry background but the last time I took mathematics and physics was in my freshman year in undergrad. I am re-learning basic calculus and physics through online resources from MIT but I was wondering if there are other resources for someone in my position. Some kind of textbook in biophysics geared towards biologist would be optimal. Or perhaps there are physics and math topics that I can focus my studies on.

Comment: Physical Biology of the Cell by Phillips is a good text book. It is a good biophysics book for both people with just a biology background or just a physics background. In terms of the math, the book goes into the details of the more complicated math in specifically labeled sections.